# Typescript: Type property depending on another property in the same object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a helper function **for others to consume**. The idea is that given an object, one key would influence the type of another key:

```
type MyHelper<T = string[]> = {
parameters: T
fn: (args: {parameters: Record<keyof T, string>}// maybe I should do something here
}

const obj:MyHelper = {
    parameters: ['a', 'b'],
    fn({ parameters }) {
        console.log(parameters) // returns {a: 'example', b: 'example'}
    }
}
```

The code works fine in the implementation, but the main idea was to be able to infer this values at the IDE. When passing something like a Class I can achieve this, but not with arrays.

Comment: You could do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiASEA2kBOUA8AVKEAewEAdgCYDOUqEAhiQPZFIhRnCoCWRA5gNoC6APigBeKAG8AUFChhqqagFsIhVGQBcULAG4pUAGZENAClnyF68TLmLlEVRoBKEAMZ1UJbDyIBXBQCM7PgAaFjZOLgEAXwBKESEANzp2Eh1IiQlXIlYoOj8AKw04RBQ7DB4AcmpykPK-csERcV1TGxULCqqauuDdAygjMSszW1UoGKbpaRalNq0oAHp5qCdXdwwAImp1qAAfKHW-dZDWDm4BXUigiTSgA), but it's not entirely clear where you want to define the type information and what you want to de derived from it.

Comment: Alternatively an identity function of sorts might help to infer generic types in this case, [see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAygUwDYDMYF4YB4AqMyAHlMmACYTxgCeA2gLoB8AFAN4wAOcATnAFtkZXhAA0MdGBgBfGAC4YnAFAxufQcOSjF+CaslhFrPgHMIi9j35CRFmACVkoXhQL0wAVwEAjbYwloXgBLMFNmGQBKbGYYADcQYIpZA2isWI5rTTsJKSjlZShaLmQYAAUNAWocegByOFqJWp9axgBuAtBIWBAfACtseCQ0dA4DNSzbbXs6hqaWxiHyyvFxww51Gy1RWWj2NbU1LogQVGQAOlQQU1ZJ7YhItZllKKA)

Comment: *[be derived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502107/typescript-type-property-depending-on-another-property-in-the-same-object#comment124626676_70502107)... Perhaps you can provide some clarifying information about how you intend for others to use it.

Comment: sure @jsejcksn. I want clients of the library to be able to construct this object, defining a method that uses the `parameters` key of the object as It's arguments. The method will be called later with the specified parameters. Both solutions above are nice, but the problem is that the client would have to define two times the parameters.

Comment: @packenbush What I meant was that you should add examples to your actual question showing how you intend for the developer to use it. That will help clarify what kinds of values you expect them to provide, and will give us (anyone who wants to help you) a better idea of how to help.